# Display html formatted text, split into page-sized chunks-- methods?

Tags: text, string-formatting

I'm building a web application to better give writers constructive criticism. Part of this involves fetching portions of html-formatted text, to be scribbled on with HTML5's canvas. As if you were marking a page with red pen.

I'm having trouble figuring out the best way to display a page-worth (500 x 600px) of text at a time. Wordcount could work, but it would also cut things off at awkward places. Character count, stripped of tags, plus space for paragraph breaks may work better, but only on a mono-type font.

So what's the best way to automatically cut up text based on size? Or do I need to look for another approach entirely?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution I eventually found:

Pomax's 'bookstyle' did the trick, using javascript and a bit of PHP to sanitize the text.

The text is loaded into a dynamically generated page-sized div until it overflows the specified clientHeight. When it hits overflow, it refills the page minus the last paragraph, then attempts to add said paragraph word by word until the bottom of the page is filled. Last, pages are 'navigated through' with hide() and show() commands.

It bottlenecks on the last paragraph each time, and I had trouble with the browser automatically trying to close my tags adding each word individually, but on the whole it does what I needed it to do.

http://pomax.nihongoresources.com/downloads/bookstyle/

All credit, of course, goes to Pomax.